# Place an icon for submit button in Zend form

Tags: php, css, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a form made by Zend Framework that needs a submit button. I want to place an icon instead of the default button. The code I have is this:

```
$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
 $submit    ->setLabel(Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->translate('Send'))
 $submit    ->setAttrib('<span class="add-on" id="login"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></span>')
             ->setIgnore(true)
```

How can I add icon instead of the default submit button in the first approach of form creation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an icon instead of submit button, tou can use `Zend_Form_Element_Note` like this:

```
$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Note('submit');
$submit->setLabel(Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->translate('Send')))
       ->setValue('<span class="add-on" id="login"><i class="icon-arrow-right" onclick="document.getElementById(\'id_form\').submit()"></i></span>');
```

Don't forget to manage the submit action on the icon with javascript as in the example (`onclick="document.getElementById(\'id_form\').submit()"`)